# How to interpret "а она все такая же..."?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Казалось бы, ей пора повзрослеть, **а она все такая же...**

I just received an IM from my girlfriend, in which she was jokingly alluding to her friend's too-*lenient* attitude -- for someone in the modelling field -- towards her daily diet. My girlfriend typically sticks to a healthy diet to stay in shape, while her friend is less so.

Given the context, I'm assuming it means:

> It would seem it's high time she grew up (and started paying more attention to what she eats), **but she's always such a...**

---

(Q1): Is some adjective (not a short-form one) omitted at the end: "such a + (adjective)"?

(Q2): Does "все" mean "always" here?

(Q3): Does "же" -- coupled with "а" -- serve as a contrasting particle? I find the position of "же" curious.

Answer (score 6):

What's omitted in such a phrase is expansion/explanation of the ellipsis to the tune of "still same old self [compared with old self who was/did/looked/etc. ...]".

Actually, "все такой/такая/такие же" translates as "same old self/selves", and the phrase is quite comprehensible without that expansion/explanation, anyway, going by the 1st part (here, food habits).

Q2: "все" means "still" here

Q3: "же" goes with "такой/такая/такие" and together those usually mean "same as", but in the context those mean "same as [old self]"

Comment: I see. What do you think of: "а она все такая же ***свободная***"?

Comment: It is meant there (пора повзрослеть), that she's **инфантильная**, _беспечная_ (by the context - not too self-responsible); an extra word is not necessary.

Comment: @Alone-zee - "а она все такая же свободная" is "and she is as free [as she used to be]" - the part in brackets is implied. The "все такой/такая/такие же" construction always has the implied part.